# Does Smalltalk have closures?

Tags: closures, smalltalk

If it has closures, can I assume that I can use many of strong functional style techniques on there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Smalltalk has closures. The following code creates a closure that returns the sum of its two arguments:

```
sum := [ :a :b | a + b ].
```

Closures are objects that can be instantiated, passed around and manipulated. To evaluate a closure you send `value`, `value:`, `value:value:`, ...

```
sum value: 1 value: 2.
```

Closures are prominently used with collections to iterate, filter, map, ... all values of a collection:

```
aCollection select: [ :each | each isOdd ].
aCollection inject: 0 into: [ :each :result | each + result ].
```

Furthermore, they are used for control structures like loops:

```
[ iterator hasNext ]
    whileTrue: [ iterator next ].
1 to: 10 do: [ :each | ... ].
```

Also conditionals are implemented using closures:

```
condition
   ifTrue: [ do this ]
   ifFalse: [ do that ]
```

Comment: Your first example only takes parameters provided by the `value:value:` message, but your example of `whileTrue:` has blocks that use the variable `iterator` which is defined outside the block.  Is one a lambda and the other a closure, or is there no difference in Smalltalk?

Comment: @quamrana: There is no (visible) difference. Most Smalltalk implementations optimize their closure objects depending on the use of outer variables. All closures understand the same messages though, so for you as a developer there is no difference.

Answer (score 6):

[Pharo](http://www.pharo-project.org/pharo-download) has them:

> all VMs have closure support required
>   for latest images

```
makeAdder := [ :x | [ :y | x + y ]].
add2 := makeAdder value: 2.
add2 value: 3.
```

Returns `5`.

But notice that

```
makeCounter := [ :init | [ init := init + 1. init ]].
```

won't work (`Cannot store into ->init …`), like (for example) in CL:

```
CL-USER> ((lambda (init) (lambda () (incf init))) 0)
#<COMPILED-LEXICAL-CLOSURE #xC7A495E>
CL-USER> (funcall *)
1
CL-USER> (funcall **)
2
CL-USER> (funcall ***)
3
```

If I'm not mistaken, this used to work before the new closure compiler was introduced. I'm not sure why it doesn't work with the new compiler.

Comment: Block and method arguments are read-only in Smalltalk. Some ancient compilers didn't check properly for block argument writes though.

Comment: But you can use a block local temp, like this: 
makeCounter := [:init | | count | count := init. [ count := count + 1. count ]].
(makeCounter value: 3) value; value